# Can I create an auto-increment column based on a foreign key value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```sql
id            int IDENTITY(1,1)  {auto increment}
foreignKeyId  int
autoId        int                {not unique}
```

I want to make the `autoId` column auto-increment based on the `foreignKeyId`, so when a row is inserted with let's say `foreignKeyId = 1`, the `autoId` must be 1, for another row with `foreignKeyId = 1` the autoId must be 2 and so on, but when a row is inserted with `foreignKeyId = 2` then `autoId` must be 1 again,

I have tried using triggers, but I believe it is not ideal to use them on large scale applications, and can fail when there are more than one insert at a time

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TableAutoIdUpdate]
ON [dbo].[Table]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @autoId int;
    
    SELECT @autoId = COALESCE(MAX(autoId), 0) + 1 
    FROM Table
    WHERE foreignKeyId IN (SELECT foreignKeyId FROM inserted);

    UPDATE Table 
    SET autoId = @autoId 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted);
END
```

Comment: ALso, your trigger **falsely** assumes that there's always only one row in `Inserted` - that is **NOT** the case! Your trigger needs to be able to handle multiple rows in `Inserted` ..... and the `SELECT MAX() + 1` approach is **highly susceptible** to producing unwanted **duplicates** in a busy system - **NOT** a recommended approach! The proper way is to have a regular, database-handled auto-increment column - not making it dependent on the value of another column in the table ...

Comment: So it's better to be handled in the application?

Comment: **NO!** Do **NOT** try to handle this in your application - really horribly bad idea. Just use a single, proper, database-managed `INT IDENTITY` column which is automatically and safely auto-incremented - don't try to do anything fancy with "auto-increment for each foreign key value" - that's just asking for trouble in the long run ....

Comment: I think you are putting to much importance on this value. Why does it matter if the "id" resets with each foreign key value? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @marc_s thank you for the advice, i was just about to make an answer saying that this is a bad idea and it is better to be handeled in the application

Comment: @SeanLange this for a centralized POS which we have many customers, i wanted the sell invoice number to start at 1 for each of our customers

Answer (score 0):

Interesting challenge. You might consider creating a sequence object, then call a function to return the value before you insert the record to handle the autoId column.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.CustomerInvoice START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION usf_GetAutoIdValue
(
    @foreignKeyId INT = NULL
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnedAutoID INT;

    IF EXISTS (
                      SELECT    1
                      FROM      CustomerOrderTable
                      WHERE     autoId = @foreignKeyID
                  )
    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnedAutoID = NEXT VALUE FOR CustomerInvoice;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @ReturnedAutoID = current_value
        FROM    sys.sequences
        WHERE   name = 'CustomerInvoice';
    END;

    RETURN @ReturnedAutoID;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

You create an additional table "idsequences" in which you will store the pairs (id, cur_val)
where id will be the primary key and contains the fk_id's of your table, cur_val will be the sequence value
to use in autoId,
then a FUNCTION to be executed in its own transaction and with ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
of which only parameter with be the fk_id of the row of your original table
in which you will either UPDATE the cur_val for an existing ID,
either INSERT a new row if such a row doesn't exists yet,
and eventually a BEFORE INSERT trigger on the original table where you will assign
autoId by calling the function with the fk_id as parameter.
You need to be aware:

- there is no guarantee you will not have holes because the allocation of the sequence number will be done in its own transaction,
- because of the BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER you will never be able to change manually the autoId unless disabling the trigger,
- the isolation level SERIALIZABLE has a cost on performance even if the function is small,
- of course fk_id can't be null,
- you still have to think about the use case "UPDATE of the fk_id"  (you could just do the same as for the INSERT or prohibit it)

I see how to test it in ORACLE PL/SQL but not fluent enough with T-SQL.

Comment: thank you for the response, but i came to the conclusion to solve it from the application

Comment: from the application you still need to handle the situation of duplicates(foreignKeyId, autoId) due to parallel actions of several clients.

Comment: yes, I am aware of that. thank you